# Данные из URL в переменную

Tags: javascript

Допустим у меня есть следующий url. При помощи getUrlVars, находящегося ниже, мы извлечём параметры id.

http://somesite.com/index.php?id=123

```
var id = getUrlVars()["id"];
```

Как вставить значение 123 в другую переменную JS файла, например вот так:
var preLandUrl="http://somesite.com/fit2/?ref=12&s=**тут должно быть 123**"

Comment: var preLandUrl="some url" + id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понял, скорее вот так:

```
var preLandUrl="http://somesite.com/fit2/?ref=12&s=" + id;
```

Изначально берем из ссылки, затем же это сохраненное в переменной значение (в нашем случае id) прибавляем к другой переменной, а там уже и делаем нужные нам манипуляции.

Answer (score 1):

Дописать в строку

```
var preLandUrl="http://somesite.com/fit2/?ref=12&s=" + 123
```